# How to handle arrow keys in a Go terminal app running on Windows 2012 or earlier?

Tags: windows, go, terminal, windows-terminal

I have a Go terminal application that after it makes remote connect, puts the terminal into a TTY Raw mode and just passes keystrokes through the conenction.

The issue I am having is that I cannot pass arrow keys when running on an Windows OS before 2012. In later Windows versions you can set `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT` and arrows keys are detected then passed, but this option does not on 2012 or earlier. For those versions no arrow key is detected.

Is their a work around for this without using VS Studio?

*To clarify, I am looking for the mechanism in the OS to allow this not a library may implement the mechanism.*

Answer (score 1):

Check if [`containerd/console`](https://github.com/containerd/console) can help, using its [latest commits](https://github.com/containerd/console/commits/1ae8d489ac812c06a28329f871c0ffcea45a63df).
It is used by a library like [`charmbracelet/wish`](https://github.com/charmbracelet/wish), and can [detect and set or not ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT](https://github.com/containerd/console/blob/1ae8d489ac812c06a28329f871c0ffcea45a63df/console_windows.go#L40) when setting [raw mode](https://github.com/containerd/console/blob/1ae8d489ac812c06a28329f871c0ffcea45a63df/console_windows.go#L177-L197).

If can make [`charmbracelet/wishlist`](https://github.com/charmbracelet/wishlist) (based on wish) work in your environment (with a Windows OS before 2012), chances are `containerd/console` can also help with you own application.

---

The two important functions are:

[`func (m *master) initStdios()`](https://github.com/containerd/console/blob/1ae8d489ac812c06a28329f871c0ffcea45a63df/console_windows.go#L32-L65)

```golang
func (m *master) initStdios() {
    // Note: We discard console mode warnings, because in/out can be redirected.
    //
    // TODO: Investigate opening CONOUT$/CONIN$ to handle this correctly

    m.in = windows.Handle(os.Stdin.Fd())
    if err := windows.GetConsoleMode(m.in, &m.inMode); err == nil {
        // Validate that windows.ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT is supported, but do not set it.
        if err = windows.SetConsoleMode(m.in, m.inMode|windows.ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT); err == nil {
            vtInputSupported = true
        }
        // Unconditionally set the console mode back even on failure because SetConsoleMode
        // remembers invalid bits on input handles.
        windows.SetConsoleMode(m.in, m.inMode)
    }

    m.out = windows.Handle(os.Stdout.Fd())
    if err := windows.GetConsoleMode(m.out, &m.outMode); err == nil {
        if err := windows.SetConsoleMode(m.out, m.outMode|windows.ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING); err == nil {
            m.outMode |= windows.ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING
        } else {
            windows.SetConsoleMode(m.out, m.outMode)
        }
    }

    m.err = windows.Handle(os.Stderr.Fd())
    if err := windows.GetConsoleMode(m.err, &m.errMode); err == nil {
        if err := windows.SetConsoleMode(m.err, m.errMode|windows.ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING); err == nil {
            m.errMode |= windows.ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING
        } else {
            windows.SetConsoleMode(m.err, m.errMode)
        }
    }
}
```

with master being:

```golang
type master struct {
    in     windows.Handle
    inMode uint32

    out     windows.Handle
    outMode uint32

    err     windows.Handle
    errMode uint32
}
```

And:

[`func makeInputRaw(fd windows.Handle, mode uint32) error`](https://github.com/containerd/console/blob/1ae8d489ac812c06a28329f871c0ffcea45a63df/console_windows.go#L177-L205)

```golang
// makeInputRaw puts the terminal (Windows Console) connected to the given
// file descriptor into raw mode
func makeInputRaw(fd windows.Handle, mode uint32) error {
    // See
    // -- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686033(v=vs.85).aspx
    // -- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683462(v=vs.85).aspx

    // Disable these modes
    mode &^= windows.ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT
    mode &^= windows.ENABLE_LINE_INPUT
    mode &^= windows.ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT
    mode &^= windows.ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT
    mode &^= windows.ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT

    // Enable these modes
    mode |= windows.ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS
    mode |= windows.ENABLE_INSERT_MODE
    mode |= windows.ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE

    if vtInputSupported {
        mode |= windows.ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT
    }

    if err := windows.SetConsoleMode(fd, mode); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("unable to set console to raw mode: %w", err)
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: Clarified the question, really looking for the mechanism not a library that may implement it

Comment: @LiamKelly That is why I linked to the console source code: it illustrates how the raw mode is set, in other words: its mechanism.

Comment: If you mine that source and extract the mechanism which answers the question above, your answer will be marked as correct

Comment: @LiamKelly i have edited the answer accordingly, but obviously test it first before marking anything as "accepted" ;)

Comment: unfortunately it does not work, as it relies on the mechanism i explicitly mention does not work in 2012: 'windows.ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT'

Comment: @LiamKelly The *all* point of this answer is to illustrate a mechanism which **detects** if `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT` and then set a raw mode with *or without* `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT`, depending if it is supported or not. Wouldn't that be what you are looking for?